# Creating many aspx pages

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I just want to ask if its okay to create many aspx pages. What i did was, i made a guitar store website that has 6 brands and each of them have their own webpage. The code is like this:

**The aspx.cs code**

```
public partial class Pages_GuitarItems1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public List<guitarItem> guitarItemList { get; set; }
public string gBrand = "Ibanez";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    guitarItemList = new List<guitarItem>();
    guitarItemList = ConnectionClassGuitarItems.GetGuitarItems(gBrand);

}

}
```

**The aspx code**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GuitarItems1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_GuitarItems1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

 <% foreach (guitarItem gItem in guitarItemList) { %>
    <div class="one-two">
        <img src="<%= gItem.itemimage1 %>"/>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="label"><%= gItem.brand %> <%= gItem.model %></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

The given code above will display the items of a guitar brand called "ibanez". The other brand would have the same code except for the string that was passed in the variable gBrand from the aspx.cs code. The second item would be in Pages_GuitarItems2 and i would pass a string called "Fender" for the second brand(so on and so forth).

And also for example if you click the brand called "Ibanez", it would have 8 guitar products in it and each have their own web page as well. I really have alot of aspx pages, thats the reason why i wanted to know if its okay to have many aspx pages or do i need to think of a way where i would just use a single webpage as template and supplement that to all brands(which i haven't really figured out yet).

Please feel free to suggest any solutions for this.

Comment: Is there any reason you could not make a single "Guitar" page in which you pass the brand as a parameter to use for pulling guitars of that brand and updating the page title?  Typically, if you find yourself repeating the same code over and over with only a single difference, then there should be a way you can keep yourself DRY (don't repeat yourself) and reuse the component.

Comment: Keeping DRY is important as lets assume you add a new piece of data to the guitar listings (I don't know, maybe size or something).  With your current method, you would have to update at least 6 pages, maybe more.  Each page you have to update brings in the possibility of forgetting to change one or more.  By reusing a single template, you change once and it affects all "brand" pages.